# cannot rename things with dependent induction?

Tags: coq

In the middle of my proof, this works

`induction H1 as [ | | | | | | | | | ].`

But, when I exchange it for

`dependent induction H1 as [ | | | | | | | | | ].`

I get "Error:
Syntax error: [tactic:ltac_use_default] expected after [tactic:tactic] (in [vernac:tactic_command]).
"

Can you seriously not choose the names of your variables when doing dependent induction? That would be crazy; I really hope I just have the syntax wrong somehow.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you precise which `dependent induction` you are using ? The standard library one ?
 If that's the case, the documentation does not advertize any `dependent induction ... as..` construction and the code does not seem to define it either (see `coq/theories/Program/Equality.v` for the definition of the tactic). 

 (As a side note, there's also a `dependent induction` tactic in the Equations library that's frequently better behaved -- but does not support `as` either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the code of `Equality.v`, here is an attempt to define a notation for dependent induction supporting the `as` clause.

```
From Coq Require Import Program.

Ltac elim_ind_as p pat := elim_tac ltac:(fun p el => induction p as pat using el) p.
Ltac do_ind_as p pat := introduce p ; (induction p as pat || elim_ind_as p pat).

Tactic Notation "dependent" "induction" ident(H) "as" simple_intropattern(pat) :=
  do_depind ltac:(fun hyp => do_ind_as hyp pat) H.


(*Example:*)
From Coq Require Vector.

Definition head : forall {A} (n:nat), Vector.t A (S n) -> A.
Proof.
  intros A n v.
  (* induction v. Would not discard the case t A 0 *)
  dependent induction v as [|a z v IH]. (* For some reason the `z` is renamed to `n`... *)
  exact a.
Defined.
```

Note that it suffers some caveat: this notation use a `simple_intropattern` whereas the standard induction tactic use an `or_and_intropattern_loc` that does not seem accessible from Ltac.
I filed an issue at [#12840](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/12840).